# Pytest monkeypatch isn't working on imported function

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Suppose there are two packages in a project: `some_package` and `another_package`.

```
# some_package/foo.py:
def bar():
    print('hello')
```

```
# another_package/function.py
from some_package.foo import bar

def call_bar():
    # ... code ...
    bar()
    # ... code ...
```

I want to test `another_package.function.call_bar` mocking out `some_package.foo.bar` because it has some network I/O I want to avoid.

Here is a test:

```
# tests/test_bar.py
from another_package.function import call_bar

def test_bar(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('some_package.foo.bar', lambda: print('patched'))
    call_bar()
    assert True
```

To my surprise it outputs `hello` instead of `patched`. I tried to debug this thing, putting an IPDB breakpoint in the test. When I manually import `some_package.foo.bar` after the breakpoint and call `bar()` I get `patched`.

On my real project the situation is even more interesting. If I invoke pytest in the project root my function isn't patched, but when I specify `tests/test_bar.py` as an argument - it works.

As far as I understand it has something to do with the `from some_package.foo import bar` statement. If it's being executed before monkeypatching is happening then patching fails. But on the condensed test setup from the example above patching does not work in both cases.

And why does it work in IPDB REPL after hitting a breakpoint?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Named importation creates a new name for the object. If you then replace the old name for the object the new name is unaffected.

Import the module and use `module.bar` instead. That will always use the current object.

```
import module 

def func_under_test():
  module.foo()

def test_func():
   monkeypatch.setattr(...)
   func_under_test
```

Comment: This is among the worst gotchas with pytest — but thanks for explaining it.

Comment: When you say "use module.bar", can you provide a code example?  I have tried `monkeypatch.setattr(module, 'bar', mock_obj)` and a few other incantations without success.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there something trick to be sure that any import will use mocked object. Because for now it is dangerous if, for example I'm trying to mock orm object

Comment: this is a property of the python language and there is no trick

Answer (score 93):

While [Ronny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746577/1953800) works it forces you to change application code. In general you should not do this for the sake of testing.

Instead you can explicitly patch the object in the second package. This is mentioned in the [docs for the unittest module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

```
monkeypatch.setattr('another_package.bar', lambda: print('patched'))
```

Comment: This is clearly the cleaner way of monkeypatching an import.

Comment: The link is to the wrong docs as far as I can tell. It should be to [the pytest monkeypatch docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch).

Comment: @LondonRob the unit-test docs have an explanation for why patching is a good idea

Comment: Let me share an example when changing a code might be a good idea: 

You have some widely used functions and write some component/integration tests.
You need to monkeypatch each model there it is used. 
 
`monkeypatch.setattr('a.val', None); monkeypatch.setattr('b.val', None)`

Comment: @Cjkjvfnby I see your point and I'm literally facing the exact issue you describe. However, personally I feel that the point still stands and it would be better to have multiple `monkeypatch` statements in the test vs modifying code structure just for the sake of testing. An exception to this would be if writing the test actually highlighted that the code wasn't written well, in which case it would justify a rewrite.

Comment: You just saved my life. I was patching the original function and not the imported one. I don't know how many times I've had this issue..

Answer (score 48):

As [Alex said,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466846/1227343) you shouldn't rewrite your code for your tests. The gotcha I ran into is which path to patch.

Given the code:

app/handlers/tasks.py

```py
from auth.service import check_user

def handle_tasks_create(request):
  check_user(request.get('user_id'))
  create_task(request.body)
  return {'status': 'success'}
```

Your first instinct to monkeypatch `check_user`, like this:

```py
monkeypatch.setattr('auth.service.check_user', lambda x: return None)
```

But what you want to do is patch the instance in `tasks.py`. Likely this is what you want:

```py
monkeypatch.setattr('app.handlers.tasks.check_user', lambda x: return None)
```

While the answers given are already good, I hope this brings more complete context.

Comment: `check_user` may be used in many files. Are you saying we need to monkeypatch different paths every time?

Comment: This was a lifesaver after an hour of searching. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate answer as @Alex but still gave you an upvote so this explanation make it click in my head a little better, thanks!

Comment: After wasting a day of my work, this answer was an elixir for me. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 2):

correct answer to OP's question:

```py
monkeypatch.setattr('another_package.function.bar', lambda: print('patched'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible reason your function may not be getting patched is if your code is using multiprocessing.

On macOS the default start method for a new process has changed from `fork` to `spawn`. If `spawn` is used, a brand new Python interpreter process is started, ignoring your recently patched function.

Fix: Set the default start method to `fork`.

```py
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork', force=True)
```

You can add this snippet to `conftest.py` inside your `tests/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I import, on module_b.py, the module to be mocked in a relative way. When I import using the full path of the module works perfectly.

Instead of `from . import module_a`,
On module_b: `from app import module_a`

then, on test_module: `from app.module_b import module_a` and `monkeypatch(module_a, "func", mock_func)`

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45466846/7287705): In this case you don't need to rewrite your code for testing.
For completeness, I want to point out that the **import order makes a difference when patching**.

Your example will work, if you import `call_bar` after the monkeypatch:

```
# tests/test_bar.py
def test_bar(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr('some_package.foo.bar', lambda: print('patched'))

    from another_package.function import call_bar
    call_bar()
    assert True
```

However, this gets tricky if you have multiple test cases with different patches, because modules are only imported once (even if you do `from another_package.function import call_bar` again in another function).

You could also use `importlib.reload`. In that case, it might make sense to do the monkeypatch in a context:

```
# tests/test_bar.py
import importlib
import sys
from another_package.function import call_bar

def test_bar(monkeypatch):
    with monkeypatch.context() as mp:
        mp.setattr('some_package.foo.bar', lambda: print('patched'))

        # Reload the module with monkeypatch
        importlib.reload(sys.modules['another_package.function'])

        call_bar()
        assert True

    # Reload the module again without monkeypatch
    importlib.reload(sys.modules['another_package.function'])
```