# Pytest Monkeypatch Doesn't Apply To Imported Function

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a module set up roughly as follows:

```py
# foo.py
def generate_things_based_on_other_things():
  # some nasty things here

# bar.py
from foo import generate_things_based_on_other_things as generate

def coo():
  generate()

# conftest.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_generate(monkeypatch):
  def mock_generate():
    print("hello!")

  monkeypatch.setattr("app.bar.generate", mock_generate)

# test_bar.py
from bar import coo

def test_coo():
  coo()
```

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306080/pytest-monkeypatch-isnt-working-on-imported-function) I made sure to monkeypatch the actual imported instance of the function. Any other path throws a `"does not exist on module"` error.
However when I run the test I hit an error, because the original function `generate` is being called, despite it being monkeypatched.
I can't figure out why this patch won't stick the way I expect it too.
I would expect this test to print "hello!".

Answer (score 1):

Your paths seem not to match. You do `from bar import coo`, but use `setattr` with `app.bar`. To be sure, you can use the other form of `setattr` instead, which takes the object and the attribute names separately, e.g.:

```py
import bar  # or "from app import bar", whichever is correct for you

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def patch_generate(monkeypatch):
    def mock_generate():
        print("hello!")

    monkeypatch.setattr(bar, "generate", mock_generate)
```

This way you can be reasonably sure that you are patching the correct object.